# Cache cart globally using key cart.id

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I want to cache the cart using key `cart.id` to save some db queries.

```
{% set cart = craft.commerce.cart %}

{% cache globally using key "cartId=" ~ cart.id ?? "empty" until cart.dateUpdated %}

{% if cart.lineItems | length %}
    {% for item in cart.lineItems %}
        {{ item.sku }},
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p>Cart has no items</p>
{% endif %}

{% endcache %}
```

1. Is caching by cart.id sufficient?
2. Is there any potential risk?
3. What is `{% set cart = craft.commerce.cart %}` actually setting when cart.id = null ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is caching by cart.id sufficient?

I would not cache the cart, it could always be changing. You would need to create a cache ID based on every aspect of the cart that could change (line items, coupons, addresses, sales, discounts, tax etc). Bottom line, do not cache dynamic things like the cart.

> Is there any potential risk?

See above.

> What is {% set cart = craft.commerce.cart %} actually setting when cart.id = null ?

You are getting an order model returned, it just does not get an ID until the first item is added to the cart and the order/cart is saved to the database.